# Return bool with if statement

Tags: c#, boolean, return

I need some help with my code since it always return false, using C# XNA 4.0

On my Game1.cs I run this code

```
if (!Connection.sendPacketBool("Check", versionPacket))
        {
            Connection.closeConnection();
            this.Exit();
        }
```

on my class connection I have this one

```
public static bool final;
public static bool sendPacketBool(String type, String data)
    {
        try
        {
            NetworkComms.SendObject(type, serverIp, serverPort, data);
            NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<string>("ClientV",
           (header, connection, array) =>
           {
               if (array == "false")
               {
                   final = false;
               }
               else
               {
                   final = true;
               }
           });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        if (!final)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The thing is final is always false except when I do

```
        public static bool final = true;
```

How can I change this code so it returns true or false? I cant do

```
if (array == "false")
               {
                   final = false;
                   return false;
               }
               else
               {
                   final = true;
                   return true;
               }
```

Since I get the error

> NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler returns void a
>   return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Thanks

Comment: Put a print statement in the exception catch block and see if it prints. I suspect that you're hitting an exception and that's why it never updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your code that sets `final` happens in a callback, and is asynchronous.  You're returning the value within a synchronous property.

As such, `final` is set *after* your property getter is returned.

The idiomatic way to handle this in C# (4+) would be to return a `Task<bool>` instead of  a bool.  This would allow you to return an object which would have the bool set when the callback completes.  You could write this as:

```
public static Task<bool> SendPacketBoolAsync(string type, string data)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    try
    {
        NetworkComms.SendObject(type, serverIp, serverPort, data);
        NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<string>("ClientV",
           (header, connection, array) =>
           {
              if (array == "false")
              {
                 tcs.TrySetResult(false);
              }
              else
              {
                 tcs.TrySetResult(true);
              }
           });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         tcs.TrySetException(ex);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: And how should I get the retun? `if (!Connection.sendPacketBool("Check", versionPacket))` that wont work

Comment: @AlvaroCarvajalNakosmai If you're using VS 2012, async/await makes this easy:  `bool check = await Connection.SendPacketBoolAsync("Check, versionPacket); if (!check) { ... }`

Comment: @AlvaroCarvajalNakosmai Then you can use a continuation - see: http://reedcopsey.com/2010/04/19/parallelism-in-net-part-17-think-continuations-not-callbacks/